# Why Node.js function doesn't return JSDom serializeDocument result?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, dnode

I have PHP script which acts as a DNode client. Then I have Node.js Dnode server which evaluates code which receives from PHP client and it returns DOM as HTML. However, Node.js acts strangely to me (beeing a Node.js newbie). It doesn't return anything, even though the returning string is not empty. My code is below:

PHP client code using [DNode-PHP library](https://github.com/bergie/dnode-php):

```
<?php
  require(__DIR__.'/../../vendor/autoload.php');
  $loop = new React\EventLoop\StreamSelectLoop();
  $dnode = new DNode\DNode($loop);
  $dnode->connect(7070, function($remote, $connection) {
    $js = 'var a = document.createElement("A");';
    $js.= 'document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(a);'
    $remote->zing($js, function($n) use ($connection) {
      print_r($n);
      $connection->end();
  });
});
$loop->run();
?>
```

Node.js server code:

```
var dnode = require('dnode');
var jsdom = require("jsdom");
var server = dnode({
  zing: function (n, cb) { 
    var document = jsdom.jsdom('<!DOCTYPE html>');
    var window = jsdom.parentWindow;
    eval(n);
    var html = jsdom.serializeDocument(document);
    // console.log(html);
    cb(html);
  }
});
server.listen(7070);
```

Console.log() clearly outputs `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><a></a></body></html>` what is expected result. But it never gets to PHP client. But what is strange, if I change line `cb(html);` to `cb('test');`, PHP outputs "test". So the problem must be somewhere on the Node.js side. But I have no idea where to look for.

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you viewing the response? Through a web browser? If so, then you're depending on whatever you're evaluating in `eval(n)` to change the DOM of the document... If nothing changes, then you won't end up seeing anything because you'll have an empty DOM other than the `html/head/body` tags. It would be worth your time confirming that you're getting an empty response back and it's not just an empty DOM.

That being said, The `eval` function has any context of you wanting to execute it on the `document/window` you declare above. As it is, it is just executing in the context of `node` itself, not on the page you are attempting to create. To fix this, try using:

`window.eval(n)`

If you take a look at the example `Creating a browser-like window object`
 on the Github page for `jsdom`, this will give you a better idea of how exactly to use this package.

https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom

What you have above should look something like this:

```
var document = jsdom.jsdom("<!DOCUMENT html>");
var window = document.parentWindow;

window.eval(n);

var html = jsdom.serializeDocument(document);

cb(html);
```

Now you'll be executing the Javascript on the DOM you were previously creating :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not in Node. When I use the server code you show in your question and try with this client code, I get the expected result:

```
var dnode = require("dnode");

var d = dnode();
d.on('remote', function (remote) {
    var js = 'var a = document.createElement("A");' +
             'document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(a);';
    remote.zing(js, function (s) {
        console.log(s);
    });
});
d.connect('localhost', '7070');
```

I don't do PHP so I don't know what the problem might be on that side.